# How to kill a running query in apache Impala 2.10 from a central point

Tags: hadoop, impala, mapr

Sometime, I have queries that are supposed to take only few seconds keeping running and running, and blocking other queries, or queries tweaked with a value set to `MT_DOP` too big which put impala on their knees.

While this is possible to kill query when using Cloudera distribution using the [UI Cloudera Manager or the API](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Interactive-Short-cycle-SQL/How-to-kill-Long-running-impala-queries/m-p/30966) I don't see such possibility with the plain version of Impala (version 2.10) currently unless you go to every worker web interface and locate the query you'd like to kill. I've check in the official [PDF manual](http://impala.apache.org/docs/build/impala-2.10.pdf) but `kill` is only a reserved word for future use.

Do you know if killing running queries is possible in plain Impala 2.10 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Killing a query should be possible from the Web UI of an Impala daemon executing it. Access impalad web UI from your browser at *http(s)://imapald.host.name.or.ip:25000/queries*, and click 'Cancel' in the Action column (see corr. Impala doc at https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_webui.html).

**EDIT**

If impalad instances are load balanced, and you use the load balancer's IP/hostname to submit the queries, you can still find out what daemon is serving as the coordinator for a particular "bad" query, and use that coordinator's Web UI to cancel it. A stdout should contain all information that you need, including direct URL of the query web page. For example:

```
$ impala-shell -i impala-lb.internal.net -d default -q "select count(*) from customer"
Connected to impala-lb.internal.net:25000
Server version: impalad version 2.10.0-xxxxxxxxx
Query: use `default`
Query: select count(*) from customer
Query submitted at: 2018-01-01 00:00:00 (Coordinator: http://actual-impalad-host.internal.net:25000)
Query progress can be monitored at: http://actual-impalad-host.internal.net:25000/query_plan?query_id=7346f2a8e2c04cee:d932a44700000000 
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 0        |
+----------+
Fetched 1 row(s) in 0.091s
$
```

Comment: That true it is possible however this is really cumbersome, you need to locate every Impala nodes and look for the query, and kill it. I will edit the question to provide more information about my need.